# ExtJS binding complex property to textfield

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

give a JSON data like this

> { name: { firstname: 'First Name', lastname: 'Last Name' } }

How can I load this data into ExtJS form field?

> First Name: [ First Name ]
>
> Last Name: [ Last Name ]

**UPDATE:**
after using this technique I arrived at second challenge when post my change back to the server Ext generate json in this format

```
{ "firstname": "New first name", "lastname": "New last name"}  
// instead of 
{ "name": { "firstname": "...", "lastname": "..."} }
```

is it expected behavior or is there anyway I can tell Ext to serialize the object back to the nest form, regards.

P.S: my Edit.js taking from Ext MVC application guide http://localhost/extjs/docs/index.html#!/guide/application_architecture

Comment: Probably should post this as a new question since the original question has been answered and accepted. Would not be fair to un-accept the original answer and few people will work for no possibility of points.  Also, this isn't a forum and responses don't work like threads. The order they appear in changes depending on votes, tab sort, etc. Use the "Edit" button to update a question when necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you map this into two separate fields in your model definition:

```
Ext.define("Person", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Model",
    fields: [
        {name: "firstname", mapping: "name.firstname"},
        {name: "lastname", mapping: "name.lastname"}
    ]
});
```